# Lex bot for online booking through credit card

Tags: amazon-web-services, bots, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

I am new to lex bot. how to create a lex bot for below use case?

Use case:

1. How can I help?
2. Booking, Payment, Others.
3. Trigger – Payment
4. Please provide your Group ID or Booking ID
5. Please provide if you want to pay using multiple card?
6. Trigger- Multiple Card
7. How many cards you would like to use for payment?  - Answer -n
8. Please provide first card – Credit Card Details – cc number, expiration date in the format – CC no/Expiration Date
9. Please provide guest’s name or booking id who should be paid using the card and amount allocation in the format – Name or booking ID/Amount
   10 .Email id of the person the invoice recipet to be sent
10. Do you require separate copy for agent and guest?
11. Repeat  7 to 10 for n number of times

I have created till 4th step, after that I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These resources should give you the pieces you need

- Example of how to capture a slot multiple times https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/94f60d43-15b7-45f4-bbbc-17889ae64ea0/en-US/banker-bot/slot-reuse
- Example of a general credit card bot https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-conversational-experiences-for-credit-card-services-using-amazon-lex/
- You may want to also check out conversational paths https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/building-paths.html
- If you are new to Lex, also worth understanding how to build good utterances/slots https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/best-practices-for-creating-amazon-lex-interaction-models/